# I am not able to get print of desired string from this code......it works in pycharm but not in vs code. I dont't understand what is wrong here?

Tags: python, string, csv, file, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2b5K.png)
I am getting this result in vs code but it is working in Pycharm and I have used the complete path of the file in both softwares...
what should i do?
is there some setting which i have to do? Also when using just the file name instead of the complete path, both pycharm and vs code are showing the file doesn't exist..

Comment: how are they saying that the file doesn't exist? what do you expect to see? also, you realize you're printing your file and not the contents, right?

Comment: If you're getting a FileNotFoundError exception then that's a definitive condition - i.e., the filename (path) as passed to the *open()* function doesn't exist or is, for some reason, inaccessible to the current user

Answer (score 0):

*print(working)* rather than *print(work)*

Or (better):

```
with open(r"C:\Users\user\vs.csv", "r") as data:
    print(data.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [pandas package](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) by command `pip install pandas` to read csv file. Using the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
# reading csv file
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\vs.csv")
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score -1):

use the below code

```
work = open(r'/Users/Documents/Python_Programs/files/china.csv','r')
working = work.read()
work.close()

print(working)
```

The variable `work` return the file object (we are using `open()` function).
The variable `working` return the file content (we are using `read()` function)

Comment: The variable *working* does **not** return the file's contents. *work.read()* does that